# Angular2 cross domain http get

Tags: ajax, web, angular, typescript, cross-domain

I am trying to fetch a JSON file from a remote server. I wrote the following module :

```
import { Component }               from '@angular/core';
import { Injectable }              from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable }              from 'rxjs/Observable';

import './rxjs-operators';


@Component({
    selector: 'map',
    templateUrl: 'map/map.component.html'
})

@Injectable()
export class MapComponent{

    private properties;

    constructor(private http: Http){

        this.properties = null;
    }

    ngOnInit(){

        this.getPropertiesInTheArea();
    }

    getPropertiesInTheArea(){

        let url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sdeering/50-jquery-function-demos/cd89f8592b96d0a79c10aa64fa43c1bf01312643/data/data.json";

        this.http.get(url)
                .map(response => response.json())
                .subscribe(
                    data => this.properties = data,
                    err => console.error(err),
                    () => console.log("Properties fetched\n\n" + JSON.stringify(this.properties))
                );
    }

}
```

This module can perfectly fetch a local JSON file :

```
let url = "http://localhost:3000/map/data.json";
```

But for a remote resource (on raw.githubusercontent.com for example) I get in the console :

> "EXCEPTION: [Exception... ""  nsresult: "0x805e0006 ()"  location: "JS frame :: http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js :: scheduleTask :: line 1241"  data: no]"
>
> Unhandled Promise rejection: Exception { message: "", result: 2153644038, name: "", filename: "http://localhost:3000/node_modules/…", lineNumber: 1241, columnNumber: 0, data: null, stack: "scheduleTask@http://localhost:3000/…" } ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Exception { message: "", result: 2153644038, name: "", filename: "http://localhost:3000/node_modules/…", lineNumber: 1241, columnNumber: 0, data: null, stack: "scheduleTask@http://localhost:3000/…" } undefined

Thanks a lot

Comment: The issue was caused by a browser plugin that blocked all outgoing requests. Works great with that thing disabled.

Answer (score -1):

This is Angular2 I presume.

I think you have a CORS issue. Check your network tab in your dev tools.

You can't fetch data from another server. (unless the other server supports jsonp or returns the right access-control headers). This probably works locally because your are serving your app from localhost also.

Comment: In this case raw.githubusercontent.com do have those headers : Access-Control-Allow-Origin:"*"